# How do I find multiple columns greater than a single column in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a single column vector that is an average of the other multiple columns (in a vector). I wish to index when each element of the matrix is is greater than the average vector. I am able to do this one at a time with:

```
idx = y1<y2
```

however if `y2` is a matrix it comes up with an error. My current solution to over come this is:

```
y1 = [y1;y1]
```

but this is rather inelegant and doesn't account for `y2`'s of unknown sizes.
Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this -

```
idx = bsxfun(@lt,y1,y2)
```

This will create a logical array of the same size as the input matrix `y2` with `1`'s where the elements in `y2` are `greater than` the corresponding elements in `y1` and `0`'s otherwise.

Best thing about **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** to solve such a problem is that it takes care of the **`expansion`** needed. So, what you would have is a generic solution without even querying for the `sizes`.

Comment: @Kamtal I tell myself that everyday!

Comment: Divakar **always** solves with `bsxfun` lol.  Much like chappjc solves everything with `accumarray`.  TBH, I only learned `bsxfun` through Divakar.  That's how I know it so well.  BTW +1!

Comment: @rayryeng Well...whenever possible rather!! :) Yeah I guess we all have our own "favorite tools". Good to see you using both `bsxfun` and `accumarray` quite efficiently these days!

Comment: Absolutely!! :) @LuisMendo

Answer (score 2):

Try using the function `repmat`.

`repmat(A,n1,n2)`  makes an `n1` x `n2` tiling of A.

So if you want to make a vector with n identical columns each containing `y1` you can run:

`repmat(y1,1,n)`

The number of columns you want is the number of columns in y2, which is

`size(y2,2)`

Thus, the solution you are looking for is:

```
idx=y2>repmat(y1,1,size(y2,2))
```

Comment: You should consider explaining your answer

Comment: Thanks for helping me remember repmat. I'll need that also!